# How do I crop a video steam that's already been resized?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm using PILs `ImageGrab` function to capture an application window in real-time for image detection with OpenCV. I've managed to scale the captured window down to increase the speed of image detection. However, I'm getting a number of false positives I can't seem to avoid. I actually only need to capture a small section of the window `761 34 1142 68`

```
while True:
    # Grab PSS Window and find size 
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('App')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    # Actual Video Loop, cropped down to the specific window,
    # resized to 1/2 size, and converted to BGR for OpenCV
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    (width, height) = (haystack_img.width // 2, haystack_img.height // 2)
    haystack_img_resized = haystack_img.resize((width, height))
    
    ########### Line in Question ##############
    haystack_img_cropped = haystack_img_resized[761: 34, 1142:68]

    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img_cropped) 
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow("Screen", haystack)
```

I tried using OpenCV to slice  the image but I get the error:

```
C:\Users\coyle\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips>C:/Users/coyle/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/coyle/OneDrive/froggy-pirate-master/avoidShips/avoidShipActual/test7.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test7.py", line 103, in <module>
    objectDetection(ships_to_avoid, 0.92)
  File "c:\Users\test7.py", line 61, in objectDetection
    haystack_img_cropped = haystack_img_resized[761:34, 1142:68]
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable
```

And I tried the `.crop` method:

```
 haystack_img_resized = haystack_img.resize((width, height))
 haystack_img_resized.crop((761,34,1164,65))
 haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img_resized)
```

which produces no error but hasn't actually cropped anything.

How do I crop my video stream?

Comment: `haystack_img_cropped = np.array(haystack_img_resized)[761: 34, 1142:68]` should work. You have to convert PIL's Image to Numpy's array before slicing.

Comment: That worked! If you post it up I'll accept it rather than my own as I wasn't sure why my version worked, appreciate the explanation!

Comment: Done! Glad to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`haystack_img_cropped = np.array(haystack_img_resized)[761: 34, 1142:68]` should work.

For your questions,

1. You have to convert PIL's Image to Numpy's array before slicing.
2. `.crop()` returns new modified PIL's Image instance rather than modifying the existing one. PIL's methods typically return a new Image instance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but loading the cropped image into a variable and using that variable worked.

```
crop = haystack_img_resized.crop((761,34,1164,65))
haystack_img_np = np.array(crop)
```

Comment: that worked because you didn't try to use *numpy slicing* on a *PIL image*, but instead here you used PIL methods on a PIL image.